# Is there a prime $q$ smaller than a given prime $p>5$ such that the inverse of $q$ modulo $p$ is an integer square?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime. For each $k=1,\ldots,p-1$ there is a unique $\bar k\in\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ with $k\bar k\equiv1\pmod p$, and we call $\bar k$ the inverse of $k$ modulo $p$. In 2014 I investigated  the set 
$$\{\bar q:\ q\  \text{is a prime smaller than}\ p\}$$
and found that it contains an integer square if $5<p<2\times 10^8$. (See http://oeis.org/A242425 and http://oeis.org/A242441.) This led me to formulate the following conjecture.

**Conjecture.** For any prime $p>5$, there is a prime $q<p$ such that the inverse $\bar q$ of $q$ modulo $p$ is an integer square.

For example, the inverse of $13$ modulo $23$ is $4^2<23$, the inverse of $5$ modulo $61$ is $7^2<61$, and the inverse of $11$ modulo the prime $509$ is $18^2<509$.

**QUESTION.** What tools in number theory are helpful to prove the above conjecture?

Comment: Well, there are about $\sqrt{p}$ squares in $[1,\ldots, p-1]$, and heuristically their inverses each have probability $\sim 1/\log(p)$ of being prime.  Since $(1 - 1/\log(p))^{\sqrt{p}} \sim \exp(-\sqrt{p}/\log p)$ goes rapidly to $0$, your conjecture is reasonable.  Of course this is not a proof.

Comment: Maybe the appearant randomness of quadratic residues will help.

Comment: Somewhat weaker version: there exists $k<p$ such that $\mathrm{core}(kp+1)$ is prime.

Comment: I have another similar conjecture: For any prime $p>80$, the set $$\{k+m:\ k,m\in\{1,\ldots,p-1\}\ \&\ km\equiv1\pmod p\}$$ contains a square.